# Calling same servlet from different jsp for different intention

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am creating a MVC application where I want my servlet to be a real controller. It should take request from view and based on request should call my DAO layer for DB interaction. I am using hibernate and populating the pojo/bean on jsp.

For eg. my one jsp is for registering the user and second is to create an ad by the user. Both jsps call the same servlet(Controller.java) and the servlet has method calls to my DAOImpl.java which has registerUser(User user) and CreateAd(Offer offer). These methods just call persist and insert the data to database.

This works fine with two servlets, but I am trying if it is possible in different way without two servlets.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling a servlet and sending a parameter which defines the action to execute. It would be something like:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="TheServlet" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register User" onclick="setAction('registerUser');" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create Ad" onclick="setAction('createAd');" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setAction(var action) {
        document.getElementById('action').value = action;
    }
</script>
```

Then, in your servlet:

```
@WebServlet("TheServlet")
public class TheServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equals(...)) {
        } else if (action.equals(...)) {
        } else ...
        //if using Java 7 or later, you could use a switch instead of ifs
    }
}
```

You can take a look into [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). Note that this is already handled by many MVC frameworks, like Spring MVC.

Comment: Thank you @Luiggi. This helps I am not using Spring in my work, yet as its a simple assignment. However is it possible to do the same without hidden parameter? I tried form names and based on it calling different method in servlet.

Comment: @SandiipPatil this option doesn't use Spring nor another framework, it is plain Servlet + JSP. Another option may be parsing the URL in your unique Servlet and define the action based on this result.

Comment: Thank you @Luiggi. If you can suggest any other way other than hidden parameter pls.

Comment: @SandiipPatil already told you in comments: parse the URL in your unique Servlet and define the action based on this result...